# How to set origin of transform translate in CSS?

Tags: css, angularjs, transform, ng-hide

I am trying to set the origin for the div, that will slide in on ngHide toggle. So far I have added:

```
.info{
  transform: translate(350px,0);
  &.ng-hide{
    transform: translate(-350px,0);
  }
}
```

And second class:

```
.more-info{
  transform: translate(350px,0);
  &.ng-hide{
    transform: translate(350px,0);
  }
}
```

However, I would like `more-info` class to come from the right-to-left - hence I am trying to set an origin of the movement (user will drag element with info class to the left, so the info class moves to the left, and more-info should move right-to-left).

Any ideas?

Comment: `transform: translate(0px,0px);` in `ng-show` right?

Comment: its acctually ng-hide - jsut fixed that thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding the same property with same value? I didn't get that part.

Comment: MDN docs for `transform-origin` might be what you're looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin